# Is it possible to store the array of objects as hash into the Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I'm using Redis with my NodeJS app. I want to store an array of objects (policies) against a key as a hash in Redis. Below is my key and value:-

**Key -** `<tenantid>~<userid> e.g. - tenant123~john123`

**Value -** `[{ ptype: 'p', v0: 'admin', v1: '/*', v2: 'GET' }, { ptype: 'p', v0: 'viewer', v1: '/post', v2: 'GET' }]`

I'm getting below error :-

```
err
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
args:Array(2) ["tenant123~john123", "[{ ptype: 'p', v0: 'admin', v1: '/*', v2: 'GET' }, { ptype: 'p', v0: 'viewer', v1: '/post', v2: 'GET' }]"]
code:"ERR"
command:"HMSET"
message:"ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command"
name:"ReplyError"
stack:"ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
    at parseError (/var/task/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/var/task/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14)"
__proto__:RedisError {constructor: , name: <accessor>}
```

Below is my NodeJS code where I'm calling hmset() to save the policies into Redis.

```
module.exports.updateCache = async (hashKey, ttl, obj, logger) => {
    logger.debug('Redis:: Key:', hashKey, ', Obj:', obj);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        myRedisClient.hmset(hashKey, obj, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                myRedisClient.expire(hashKey, ttl);
                console.log('result:', result);
                resolve(true);
            }
            console.log('closing redis connection');
            myRedisClient.quit();
        });
    });
}
```

I tried to debug a lot but could not fix this. Is it not possible to store an array of objects against a hashkey in Redis?

Please assist. Thanks

**[Update]**

**New code:-**

```
module.exports.updateCache = async (hashKey, ttl, obj, logger) => {
    logger.debug('Redis:: Key:', hashKey, ', Obj:', obj);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        myRedisClient.hmset(hashKey, JSON.stringify(obj), (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                myRedisClient.expire(hashKey, ttl);
                console.log('result:', result);
                resolve(true);
            }
            console.log('closing redis connection');
            myRedisClient.quit();
        });
    });
}
```

**Error:-**

```
err
ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
args:Array(2) ["tenant123~john123", "[{"ptype":"p","v0":"admin","v1":"/*","v2":"GET"}]"]
code:"ERR"
command:"HMSET"
message:"ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command"
name:"ReplyError"
stack:"ReplyError: ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command
    at parseError (/var/task/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (/var/task/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14)"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible**.

Redis stores everything in string or in its string representation. you can't store array of objects or even object(except string) in redis.

There is no direct means to store objects - it can be done only via **serialization** and storing resultant byte-array.

Comment: Sorry, can share a sample code explanation serialization here please? I tried JSON.stringify(obj) but that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Redis store [strings](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) so you must serialize your JSON object/array to store them, and then deserialize them when you read those keys.

```
module.exports.updateCache = async (hashKey, ttl, obj, logger) => {
    logger.debug('Redis:: Key:', hashKey, ', Obj:', obj);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        myRedisClient.hmset(hashKey, { array: JSON.stringify(obj) }, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.error(err);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                myRedisClient.expire(hashKey, ttl);
                console.log('result:', result);
                resolve(true);
            }
            console.log('closing redis connection');
            myRedisClient.quit();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is not working. "Getting error ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hmset' command". I tried using your solution by passing array of object but getting this error

Comment: fixed the answer, hmset, I wrote the code for hset. Docs will help you in these cases

Answer (score 0):

The function `hmset` is deprecated as of Redis v4.0. Use `hset` instead.

Using your newer example, something like

```
myRedisClient.hset(hashKey, , 'name', JSON.stringify(obj), (err, result) => ...
```

could work. Failures. What was failing, the cause of the error? Pay close attention to the keyname - if this is calling a key by the same name but is a different datatype such as a set, this call would fail.